# List of Autosys Jobs from Calendar Input

Tags: autosys

I need to extract the list of Jobs running with a specific calendar in Autosys.
Is there any autosys command to extract this information?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

There is no CLI for that. You can only do by DB select or via WCC